# SQL Double Result set being returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following script loops through the result set and displayes each record twice, please advise what is causings this. if in the WHERE clause the transaction_date is uncommented the results returend are for day and are corrcet, the transaaction_date is commented out to do a full load load regardless of the date, this is when the double result set is returned.

Thank you for your help

```
/* Sales by Customer
*/

/*
      Variables Declared
*/
      DECLARE @Loaddate DATETIME
      DECLARE @Branch_no TINYINT
/* 
      Set Variables
*/
      SET @branch_no = 0  
    WHILE @branch_no  < 1

    BEGIN
    SET @Branch_no = @branch_no + 1
    SET @Loaddate = (SELECT last_txn_date FROM wf_cntl_details w
                                    WHERE w.depot_no = @Branch_no 
                                    AND tbl_name = 'Invoice_Header')

SELECT h.depot_no,h.customer_code,h.transaction_date,h.transaction_no
FROM ft_inv_hdr_sales h
                  INNER JOIN ft_Inv_dtl_sales d      ON 
                              h.depot_no = d.depot_no AND h.transaction_date = d.transaction_date  AND
                              h.transaction_no = d.transaction_no

WHERE d.depot_no = @Branch_no  -- and h.transaction_date = @Loaddate
GROUP BY h.depot_no,h.customer_code,h.transaction_date,h.transaction_no 

END
```

Comment: Test your query with hardcoded values for your variables first and without the while loop. You may not be joining the tables on all the necessary fields.

Answer (score 0):

There must be multiple (most prob 2) entries in ft_inv_hdr_sales table for a same customer but of different transaction_date.

Comment: I have confirmed that the resul set is double, by inserting the result set into  temp a table and and then comparing the results through a qry and within excel to ensure a completeness

Comment: What I am saying is that in your parent table (ft_inv_hdr_sales) itself there may be multiple records for a same customer.  Try this: SELECT customer_code, COUNT(1) FROM ft_inv_hdr_sales GROUP BY customer_code HAVING COUNT(1) > 1. Check if this query gives any output.